# Gravar cadastro no BD

Tags: c#, sql-server

Olá, estou tendo um problema de gravação no Sql Server, eu tenho duas tabelas(cargo e usuario), quando eu tento gravar o registro do C#, aparece o erro: (System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
ObjetoTransferencia.Usuario.Cargo.get returned null.)

A minha tabela usuario(IdCargo) faz referência a tabela cargo (IdCargo e Descrição)para que o Combobox apresente os cargos disponíveis para escolha.

Porém, ao tentar gravar pára na linha conforme foto e informa a mensagem de erro, o meu programa está feito em camadas.

Gostaria da ajuda da comunidade para poder solucionar este erro.
OBS: O meu Objeto Cargo, está como objeto dentro de objeto.

Grato !!

BLL = camada de negócios para inserção

```
public String Inserir(Usuario usuario)
        {
            try
            {
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.LimparParametros();

                //acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@IdUsuario", usuario.IdUsuario);
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@Nome", usuario.Nome);
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@StatusUsu", usuario.StatusUsu);
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@CPF", usuario.CPF);
                //acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@DataCadastro", usuario.DataCadastro);
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@LoginUsu", usuario.LoginUsu);
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@Senha", usuario.Senha);
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@ConfirmarSenha", usuario.ConfirmarSenha);
                acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@IdCargo", usuario.Cargo.IdCargo);


                String idUsuario = acessoBancoDeDadosSqlServer.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "uspUsuarioInserir").ToString();

                return idUsuario;
            }
            catch ( Exception exception )
            {
                return exception.Message;
            }
```

DTO = Objeto Transferência

```
namespace ObjetoTransferencia
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public Int32 IdUsuario { get; set; }

        public String Nome { get; set; }

        public String CPF { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        public String LoginUsu { get; set; }

        public String Senha { get; set; }

        public String ConfirmarSenha { get; set; }       

        public Cargo Cargo { get; set; }

        public Boolean StatusUsu { get; set; }

    }

}
```

GUI = Apresentação

```
private void toolStripSalvar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

            usuario.CPF = Convert.ToString(maskedTextBoxCpf.Text);
            usuario.Nome = Convert.ToString(txtNome.Text).ToUpper();
            usuario.LoginUsu = Convert.ToString(txtLogin.Text);

            Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
            usuario.Cargo.IdCargo = Convert.ToInt32(usuario.Cargo.IdCargo);
            usuario.Cargo.Descricao = Convert.ToString(usuario.Cargo.Descricao);

            usuario.Senha = Convert.ToString(txtSenha.Text);
            usuario.ConfirmarSenha = Convert.ToString(txtConfirmarSenha.Text);

            if ( radioButtonAtivo.Checked == true)
            {
                usuario.StatusUsu = true;
            }
            else
            {
                usuario.StatusUsu = false;
            }

            UsuarioNegocios usuarioNegocios = new UsuarioNegocios();

            String retorno = usuarioNegocios.Inserir(usuario);

            try
            {
                Int32 idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(retorno);

                MessageBox.Show("Usuário inserido com sucesso.\n\nCódigo: " + idUsuario.ToString(), "SUCESSO !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                AtualizarGrid();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível inserir registro.\n\nDetalhes: " + retorno, "ERRO !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: depure seu código e presta atenção na classe cargo, pois IdCargo vem da onde? Outra coisa notória é quantidade de `Convert.To`, desde de quando a propriedade `.text` do `TextBox` e `MaskTextBox` ja retornam string. Vc está instanciando Cargo, se ele não alimenta CargoID no construtor,, logo ele será nulo. Posta sua classe Cargo!!!

Comment: Altere sea classe Usuario para ter um construtor que inicializar o Cargo.

Comment: Vagner, nesse caso, seria interessante aceitar a resposta que lhe forneceu a solução para ajudar a outros na comunidade que passarem pelo menos problema. Acredito que foi a do @TheRafa

Answer (score 0):

Você está pegando os valores da própria definição de cargo, você instancia o Objeto e tenta usar o próprio valor ele, acredito que o IdCargo e a Descricao deveriam vir de outra fonte, e tecnicamente para essa lógica não seria necessário o Convert.ToInt32 e Convert.ToString pois como está pegando do mesmo campo são os mesmo valores.

```
        Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
        usuario.Cargo.IdCargo = Convert.ToInt32(usuario.Cargo.IdCargo);
        usuario.Cargo.Descricao = Convert.ToString(usuario.Cargo.Descricao);
```

Verifique sua definição da classe Cargo se o campo IdCargo não está como nulável

```
        public class Cargo
        {
            public int? IdCargo {get; set;}
            public string Descricao { get; set; }
        }
```

Acredito que se a sua lógica estiver de acordo com o que queira se remover o Convert.ToInt32 já irá parar de dar a exceção.

```
        usuario.Cargo.IdCargo = Convert.ToInt32(usuario.Cargo.IdCargo);
```

para

```
        usuario.Cargo.IdCargo = usuario.Cargo.IdCargo;
```

Comment: Galera, muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos. Eu só precisei informar onde eu iria guardar a informação conforme foi me informado: 
If(ComboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
   usuario.Cargo = (Cargo)ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
}
Com isto já resolvi o meu problema. Muito grato mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

A causa do **erro** está nítida:

Você instancia um `Usuario`, começa a preencher as informações do usuário, instancia um `Cargo` - que não está tendo suas propriedades preenchidas - e tenta preencher uma propriedade de outro objeto do tipo `Cargo` que está dentro do usuário e ainda não foi inicializado a partir da informação do proprio objeto nao inicializado. É um combo com dois pontos onde vai estourar a exception de referência nula. Justamente nesse ponto da sua "camada de apresentação":

```
...
Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
usuario.Cargo.IdCargo = Convert.ToInt32(usuario.Cargo.IdCargo);
...
```

Acredito eu que você pretendia fazer algo assim depois de inicializar o cargo:

```
cargo.IdCargo = 1; // Algum valor válido com uma origem que faça sentido
```

Mas é difícil dizer. Este seu cenário está bem bagunçado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer pegar a seleção do combobox, você deve fazer uma conversão direta do objeto selecionado.
Se a lista que compõe o combobox for de cargos faça assim:

```
usuario.Cargo.IdCargo = ((Cargo)ComboBox1.SelectedItem).IdCargo;
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
usuario.Cargo = (Cargo)ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Você ainda pode validar se o combobox possui seleção, senão vai disparar execeção na hora da conversão direta:

```
If(ComboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
   usuario.Cargo = (Cargo)ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
}
```